# Create data structure

Tags: go

I have a json structure in database column each row has below mentioned json

`{"DeviceId":"954b9c1a58fb3879","SmsData":[{"sender":"XXXXXXXX ","sms":"YYYY"},{"sender":"kkkkk","sms":"TTT"}]}`

I need to create data structue by parsing each row data to calculate count on basis of send, sms and date. i.e if sender, sms and date is same then increase counter by 1 and keep the data structure in such as way to get sender, sms, date and count.

sender sms count
  xxx->yyy->2
       zzz->3

ttt -> yyy->6
         kkk->5

So how to create and managed structure in Go?

Comment: What have you tried? Show your current attempt. What problems are you having with it?

Comment: https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Answer (score 0):

Go provides you many handy ways of dealing with things like these, and by many ways, I mean one way and it's struct and interface types. From the look of your data, a `map[string]interface{}` is your best bet.